# Imagining things in more than 3 dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra

How do mathematicians imagine things while dealing with more than three dimensions in linear algebra?Is there a way to imagine such things or is it not possible?

Comment: There's a joke about a mathematician giving a talk about some 9-dimensional object. When asked, how do you visualize something in 9 dimensions, she replied, you visualize an infinite-dimensional space, and then cut it down to 9.

Answer (score 4):

How do you picture a cube (or a three-dimensional sphere, or any three-dimensional object) on a 2-dimensional piece of paper ? You draw its projection.

Well, it's the same with higher-dimensional objects.

Answer (score 1):

I once nearly managed to properly visualize a hypercube in 4 dimensions - but it hurt, and I stopped.  I've had a little luck imaginarily moving my hands over a four dimensional object; the 3d image in your head would be that you're moving your hand through a normal projection of (say) a hypercube, but you can imagine feeling corners along the appropriate planes.  Another trick is that you can assign colors to the 4th axis - in theory, you can assign points 6 dimensions like that, though I've never found it particularly intuitive.  None of these are particularly standardized, but they're things that have helped me a bit.  Beyond that, there's a youtube video I found that gives some ways of dealing with N-dimensional objects: [Thinking visually about higher dimensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwAD6dRSVyI), by 3Blue1Brown.  In general, dealing with N dimensions is difficult, but gets a *somewhat* easier with practice.  If you're doing math, specifically (like linear algebra), thankfully the notations mean you don't usually *have* to imagine them visually, or we wouldn't get very far.  While projections do help, be careful, because sometimes they can lead you astray - some rules that hold in 2 and 3 dimensions don't for higher dimensions.  (For instance, I was surprised to discover that things don't rotate around axes; they rotate around planes, and can rotate around multiple perpendicular planes at once.  This is difficult to infer from a projection alone.)